# Symfony 1.4 form won't validate

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here. This is my first Symfony project, and I'm stumped on why the form won't validate.

To test the application, I fill out all of the form inputs and click the submit button and it fails to validate every time. No idea why.

Any help will be appreciated!

The view -- modules/content/templates/commentSuccess.php :

```
<?php echo $form->renderFormTag('/index.php/content/comment') ?>
<table>
    <?php echo $form['name']->renderRow(array('size' => 25, 'class' => 'content'), 'Your Name') ?>
    <?php echo $form['email']->renderRow(array('onclick' => 'this.value = "";'), 'Your Email') ?>
    <?php echo $form['subject']->renderRow() ?>
    <?php echo $form['message']->renderRow() ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The controller -- modules/content/actions/actions.class.php :

```
public function executeComment($request)
{
    $this->form = new ContentForm();

    // Deal with the request
    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $this->form->bind($request->getParameter("content"));

        if ($this->form->isValid())
        {

            // Do stuff
            //$this->redirect('foo/bar');
            echo "valid";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "invalid";
        }
    }
}
```

The form -- /lib/form/ContentForm.class.php :

```
class ContentForm extends sfForm {

    protected static $subjects = array('Subject A', 'Subject B', 'Subject C');

    public function configure()
    {
        $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('content[%s]');
        $this->widgetSchema->setIdFormat('my_form_%s');
        $this->setWidgets(array(
            'name' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
            'email' => new sfWidgetFormInput(array('default' => 'me@example.com')),
            'subject' => new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => array('Subject A', 'Subject B', 'Subject C'))),
            'message' => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(),
        ));
        $this->setValidators(array(
            'name' => new sfValidatorString(),
            'email' => new sfValidatorEmail(),
            'subject' => new sfValidatorString(),
            'message' => new sfValidatorString(array('min_length' => 4))
        ));
        $this->setDefaults(array(
            'email' => 'me@example.com'
        ));
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance! I'll edit this post as needed during progress.

**EDIT**
I've changed my view code to this:

```
<?php echo $form->renderFormTag('/frontend_dev.php/content/comment') ?>

<table>
    <?php if ($form->isCSRFProtected()) : ?>
        <?php echo $form['_csrf_token']->render(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <?php echo $form['name']->renderRow(array('size' => 25, 'class' => 'content'), 'Your Name') ?>
    <?php echo $form['email']->renderRow(array('onclick' => 'this.value = "";'), 'Your Email') ?>
    <?php echo $form['subject']->renderRow() ?>
    <?php echo $form['message']->renderRow() ?>

    <?php if ($form['name']->hasError()): ?>
        <?php echo $form['name']->renderError() ?>
    <?php endif ?>


    <?php echo $form->renderGlobalErrors() ?>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

This gives a required error on all fields, and gives "    csrf token: Required.
" too.

My controller has been updated to include $this->form->getCSRFToken(); :

```
public function executeComment($request)
    {
        $this->form = new ContentForm();
        //$form->addCSRFProtection('flkd445rvvrGV34G');
        $this->form->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat('contact[%s]');

        $this->form->getCSRFToken();

        // Deal with the request
        if ($request->isMethod('post'))
        {
            $this->form->bind($request->getParameter("content[%s]"));

            if ($this->form->isValid())
            {
                // Do stuff
                //$this->redirect('foo/bar');
                echo "valid";
            }
            else
            {
                $this->_preWrap($_POST);
            }
        }
    }
```

Still don't know why it's giving me an error on all fields and why I'm getting the csrf token: Required.

Comment: I seem to recall that you need to render the hidden fields in your view to get the CSRF fields.  The failed binding is likely a CSRF failure.

Comment: Symfony requires all forms to have CSRF fields?

Comment: I added the CSRF fields but it still fails. It just says my original fields are required -- despite that they are filled out.

Comment: You can disable CSRF by setting `csrf_secret: false` in the `settings.yml` file for your app.  Sorry this didn't help though.

Answer (score 4):

When you take full control of a Symfony form, as you are doing according to the code snippets in your OP, you will have to manually add the error and csrf elements to your form:

```
// Manually render an error
<?php if ($form['name']->hasError()): ?>
    <?php echo $form['name']->renderError() ?>
<?php endif ?>

<?php echo $form['name']->renderRow(array('size' => 25, 'class' => 'content'), 'Your Name') ?>

// This will echo out the CSRF token (hidden)
<?php echo $form['_csrf_token']->render() ?>
```

Check out [Symfony Docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/03-Forms-for-web-Designers) on custom forms for more info. Also, be sure to add CSRF back to your form, there is no reason to leave it out, and will protect from outside sites posting to your forms.

Comment: I tried using just <?php echo $form ?> but got the same errors. 

Please have a look at my edit. I've updated the view and controller code, but I'm seeing the same error. 

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: According to your OP, you should be getting a 'invalid' message when you submit the form. Also, I would recommend doing your dev work through the dev controller (whatever-your-controller-is_dev.php), so you don't get hung up dealing with caching issues. Clear cache, `php symfony cc` and reload the page, then try your submission.

Comment: Also, that's the page with the steps I followed. I even used almost identical values for everything. No idea what went wrong with it...

Comment: Just did that and still got the same errors. csrf token: Required. and *Required next to all form inputs. :(

And, I'm using the frontend_dev.php thing instead of index.php. I forgot to update the post when I switched it a little bit ago. Sorry about that.

Comment: When you are viewing the form, view the html source, and validate that the csrf token is indeed rendering. You should see it under the start of your form tag.

Comment: I did that and it is rendering. From the source. When I print_r($_POST), it displays the token. And, it's in the source as well:
input type="hidden" name="contact[_csrf_token]" value="87674fddb316073a8c10d6e561595eeb" id="contact__csrf_token" />

Comment: Is that a typo in your actions.class.php, where you are setting the namespace to be `contact`, but are binding the form to `content`? You could try doing `var_dump($request->getParameter('_csrf_token'));` and make sure it's coming through.

Comment: Whoops. Yes. That was a typo. I fixed it. Getting the same error. The var_dump is telling though. var_dump gives NULL. However, shouldn't it be $_POST['content']['_csrf_token']? I'm not sure how get that with getParaemter.

Comment: I took out the [content] begining to the name='s. var_dump gives the csrf now. And it still says csrf token: Required.

So, it's coming through but not passing.

Comment: Now I've got to stop telling me all fields are required, but ifValid() still fails.

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($form->getGlobalErrors());` to see why ifValid is failing. What I would suggest is re-reading the docs again and see where you messed up the namespacing.

Comment: var_dump($form->getGlobalErrors()); gives an empty array: array(0) { }

I guess it's back to the docs. Thanks for all the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be wise to render any global form errors:

```
$form->renderGlobalErrors()
```

Comment: Per Duane's comment, I tried adding CSRF fields. It didn't fix the issue, so I took them out. But, now I'm getting     csrf token: Required.


Can't seem to get rid of that error now. I wasn't getting it before.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a typo in your executeComment function ?

```
    $this->form->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat('contact[%s]');
```

and later:

```
    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter("content[%s]"));
```

You should write:

```
    $this->form->getWidgetSchema()->setNameFormat('content[%s]');
```

But this line is not necessary you can delete it (the NameFormat is already done in your form class).

And the $request->getParameter("content[%s]") will not word ("content[%s]" is the format of the data sent by the form), you should use:

```
    $this->form->bind($request->getParameter("content"));
```

Or best, to avoid this kind of typo:

```
public function executeComment($request)
{
    $this->form = new ContentForm();
    // Deal with the request
    if ($request->isMethod('post'))
    {
        $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));

        if ($this->form->isValid())
        {
            // Do stuff
            //$this->redirect('foo/bar');
            echo "valid";
        }
        else
        {
            $this->_preWrap($_POST);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem with an admin generated backend form. When I tried to apply css schema changes with this code, it broke the token. It didn't break right away. That signals to me this is a bug in Symfony 1.4

```
$this->setWidgetSchema(new sfWidgetFormSchema(array(
      'id'                 => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
      'category'           => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => $this->getRelatedModelName('RidCategories'), 'add_empty' => false)),
      'location_id'        => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'title'              => new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('class' => 'content')),
      'content'            => new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(), array('class' => 'content')),
      'content_type'       => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'schedule_date'      => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'post_date'          => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'display_status'     => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'parent_id'          => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'keyword'            => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'meta_description'   => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'update_frequency'   => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'keywords'           => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'allow_content_vote' => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'rating_score'       => new sfWidgetFormInputText()
)));
```